# Hibernate, one-to-many association with composite key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, one-to-many, composite-key

I would like to ask you just a little confirmation about how I am currently mapping my objects in a database through Hibernate. Here is the problem statement:

> I have two entities, User and Message. A User can be associated to many Messages
>   A User is uniquely identified by the username. So primary key is the username.
>   A Message is uniquely identified by the username of the user associated and by another field, rxTime. So in this case it is a composite key (username, rxTime)

Here is how i am currently mapping this via XML

```
<hibernate-mapping package="my.package">
    <class name="User" table="USERS">
        <id name="username" column="USERNAME_ID"> </id>
        <set name="messages" table="MESSAGES"
                inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="USERNAME_ID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Message" />
        </set>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping package="my.package">
    <class name="Message" table="MESSAGES">
        <composite-id >
            <key-many-to-one name="user" class="User" column="USERNAME_ID"/>
            <key-property name="startRxTime" column="startRxTime"/>         
        </composite-id>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Questions:
- Am I doing it right? I am new to hibernate and I am not sure that this is the right way to do one-to-many associations.
- I am encountering some performance issues when querying the DB. When I try to get a list of messages order by RxTime i see that many queries are generated by hibernate to obtain the result. This will be the next thing to investigate but i am afraid that the way i am mapping the objects is leading to this inefficiency. Is it right?

I am aware that this looks like a trivial database design but on the web I've found a lot of different ways to do it and it is not clear for me which is the best one.

Thanks a lot for your eventual asnwers.

Cheers

Comment: If you are starting with Hibernate, I would suggest to use JPA annotations instead of XML Hibernate mappings

Comment: Hi, thanks fot the suggestion. Unfortunately i am afraid i went to far with the development and this will take a strong refactoring. By the way i will consider this if i don't find any other quick solution.

Comment: When you are querying based on RxTime, did you create index based on that column? Hibernate doesn't create it for you.

Comment: If you mean how i generate the values of the keys for both table, they are not autmatically generated by hibernate but they are supposed to be passed very time I add a new user or message to the db. If I misunderstood, i need to ask you to be a little more specific. I am newbie and it might be that i didn't understand completely the question. Thanks for your patience

Comment: I meant DB index. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index